# Active Directory / Map Network Drive / Likewise-open

Tags: networking, directory, drive

The Situation:

Windows Active Directory with a Domain, Users have specific private Network Drives automatically mapped onto their machine, when they log in on a windows machine.
I want to achieve the same with the Ubuntu Desktops.

How to do that?

Another Problem is that the home directories arent private. If I log into `user1` logout and log in as `user2`. I can see `home/Likewise-open/user1` and `home/Likewise-open/user2` and I can access both from each account.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is older than dirt, but just in case anyone else stumbles across it I found the answer to the first part at http://klungvik.com/blog/2009/08/28/automount-windows-ad-shared-drives-in-linux/.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Sisk. Please don't post answers with just links. These links could die and no one would know what was behind it. We try to keep this place as informative as possible. So please, copy and paste the steps in that link into your answer instead. You can [edit your answer](http://askubuntu.com/posts/517313/edit) by clicking the `edit` button right underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

This is copy-paste from the link provided earlier, in case the link at some point dies...

Likewise-open plug in to pam to authenticate Windows AD users on a linux box. pam-mount will mount shared drives at login time using the login credentials. There is no need for samba to do this, and no need to write down your username and password in a file.

```
Install pam-mount.
sudo apt-get install libpam-mount
sudo mkdir -p /media/shared_folder_name
Set up shared drives to mount:
sudo gedit /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml
<!-- Volume definitions -->
<!-- <volume fstype="cifs" server="server ip adress" user="*" path="to_shared_folder" mountpoint="shared_folder_name" /> -->
Make gdm automatically mount shared folders at login:
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/gdm
At the bottom of the file, add the following:
@include common-pammount
```

Reboot and log in again. The shared drive should be available.